# Why do some websites have styles that aren't assigned to elements when I inspect the markup?

Tags: html, css

I found something really weird to me [on Github](https://github.com/henrikingo/impress.js/tree/myfork/examples/2D-navigation):

```css
body.impress-on-applepie #applepie-image,
body.impress-on-applepie-pro #applepie-image,
body.impress-on-applepie-con #applepie-image,
body.impress-on-conclusion #applepie-image,
body.impress-on-overview #applepie-image {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition:  opacity 2s;
}
```

```html
<body class="impress-not-supported">
...
</body>
```

As you can see, `<body>` only has the class `impress-not-supported`, so why are there so many other classes in the stylesheet which do not exist or aren't declared in HTML, and how do these styles work?

(these selectors are start from line 197 in presentation.css file.)

Comment: *why there are many classes?* .... As it seems some sort of plugin they are ways to style your html based on some options you select from the plugin I guess, the CSS could have tons of options but that doesn't mean all need to be on the HTML.

Comment: Classes that don't apply to the HTML are simply ignored. Why they exist we can't tell you, but presumably there's a script at works that applies classes when necessary.

Comment: I assume the impress plugin removes the "not supported" class and adds the relevant other classes after it tests that the browser supports whatever methods it's using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes declared in CSS can be used (and probably are) with JS events. The `body`'s classname is changed dynamically by JS.

The default class has no special styles, it's the same as the `class` attribute won't be there.

*and how do these body.xxx work?*
It works the same way as any class on other HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

They are body classes controlled using Javascript potentially to add feature or browser detection. After they can be targetted with CSS.

Modernizer is an example of a service that uses them:
http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/

Answer (score 1):

Some part of html DOM tree can be loaded in the page ***after*** page loaded completely based on JavaScript or JQuery functions which maybe related on user behavior or not (I mean automatically run some functions after page load event).

So you won't be able to see this parts of html DOM tree in compile time but those styles are needed to be exist in page.